# Xcode 10.1 simulator showing black screen

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode10.1

I have a Xcode 10.1, my system is macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 iMac middle 2010. Trying to launch a simulator but it showing only black screen. There are a lot of topics about it, but they don't work for me. I tried  Reset content and Setting, delete Derived Data, tested on many simulators with different iOS versions. Maybe I missed something? App works great on physical devices (iPhone 6, SE, 5s). I need to test the app with X-iPhones, but can't do this. Please help.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have the same problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no, but it works for me on MacBook Air with Xcode 10.1 and Hight Sierra. I still don't know the reason. If you will solve this problem, please, let me know how in this branch

Comment: At the time I am reading this, its been 1 year and 11 months and still no answer. I got the same problem and couldn't find any solution so far.